# Renaming sheets to value from cell X depending on value on cell Y on the same row

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to create a new worksheet and name it depending on a value in a drop down list and loop it for every "yes" in the list.

The last string is not working and I have no idea how to loop the renaming process to fetch the correct name.

For example: If cell I65 has the value of "AP" I want the newly generated sheet to be named to the value in A65.

```vb
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, was As Worksheet

Set rng = Range("A1:A3")
Sheets("Setup").Select
For Each cell In Range("I48:I85")
    If cell = "AP" Then
        Sheets("AP").Select
        Sheets("AP").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
        Dim AP(2) As Worksheet
        Set AP(2) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AP (2)")
        AP(2).Name = Worksheets("Setup").Range("A48:A85").Value
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I did not fully understand what you are trying to do, This statement looks suspicious:
AP(2).Name = Worksheets("Setup").Range("A48:A85").Value
you are trying to rename a worksheet with a range of values? -not allowed.
use a single cell like this or concatenate the values in the range before you remane.
AP(2).Name = Worksheets("Setup").Range("A48").Value

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the following code.

(1) `Range("A48:A85").Value` returns an array of values which cannot be used as a name. I have used the `Offset`-function to get the cell in col `A` of the same row.

(2) No need to use `Select`. Read (and understand) [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

(3) Always qualify all worksheets, ranges and so on. With other words: Tell VBA which worksheet from which workbook you are using.

(4) I have used `ActiveWorkbook` in the `With`-clause, but I don't like it. Make up your mind on which workbook you are working. If it is the workbook the code lives, use `ThisWorkbook` instead. It it is another workbook, it's better to assign it to a workbook variable (eg when you open it). Especially in larger project, don't rely on `Activeworkbook`.

(5) You are declaring your variable `AP` as array with 2 elements. I guess you just wanted to name the variable similar to the new created sheet, but using an array and writing `AP(2)` is highly confusing. Just name it `AP2` (or `newWs` or `APCopy`)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range

With ActiveWorkbook   ' <-- Better change that.
    Set ws = .Sheets("Setup")
    For Each cell In ws.Range("I48:I85")
        If cell = "AP" Then
            .Sheets("AP").Copy Before:=.Sheets(1)
            Dim AP2 As Worksheet
            Set AP2 = .Sheets("AP (2)")
            AP2.Name = cell.Offset(0, -8).Value
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```